# Overrive bootstrap dropdown to call an ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i need to fire an ajax load when dropdown button is clicked.
i don't know why it's not working, maybe bootstrap has some prevent.default on its dropdown

```
<a id="country" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
    <span class="badge bg-success2">{{ ScadNumNav }}</span>
</a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#country').click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $.get("{% url 'azzera_notifiche' %}");
            doSomething();
            setInterval(doSomething, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bootstrap Dropdown provides some events. You could check for the `show.bs.dropdown` event like:

```
$('#country').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    // do something…
});
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

You should just download the original dropdown JS code and edit it to your wish. Then combine and minify (if you want) the source again.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js

Please look at the toggle method.